# Python file downloading fails

Tags: python, python-requests

New to python and attempting to download the NIST NVD JSON files. I have tried several methods but it only write about 324 bytes file. If I do one file that does in fact work but there are several files to download for this.

I did try to adjust the chunk_size but still can't get a 1 to 6mb zip file to download

```
from requests import get

def download(url, filename):
    response = get(url, stream = True)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
    print('Downloaded! ', filename)

with open('NVD_JSON_SOURCE_URLS.txt') as f:
    for line in f:    
        filename = line.split('/')[-1]
        url = line
        download(url, filename)
```

The input works and it starts the downloads, just never completes them. Clearly I am missing something frustratingly simple here but after 2 days I am not getting any closer. Thanks.

Comment: from requests import get

def download(url, filename):
    response = get(url, stream = True)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
    print('Downloaded! ', filename)
with open('NVD_JSON_SOURCE_URLS.txt') as f:
    for line in f:    
        filename = line.split('/')[-1]
        url = line
        download(url, filename)

Comment: and I clearly also can't figure out the posting...very sorry about that mess. I hope someone can read it.

Comment: there's a code format button (looks like {}). Just highlight your code and click the magic button! It took me forever to find it too.

Comment: Can you provide one url?

Comment: `open(filename, "wb")` I think you should use `wb+` , `+` means create this file if not exists.

Comment: include NVD_JSON_SOURCE_URLS.txt content as is

Answer (score 0):

I find chunking to be painful for instances like this in Python. This approach has worked for me frequently:

```
import requests
import shutil

def download_file(url, filename):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

This streams the whole file to memory then writes it. So wouldn't work for huge files, but you are only talking about a couple of MB should work fine.

Comment: Or, you could simply use `f.write(r.content)` if the file is small.

Answer (score 0):

I think `line` has some whitespace characters, so if you remove the whitespace characters from `line` using `strip()`, the code should work.

```
for line in f:    
    line = line.strip()
    ...
```

I tested it and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a line break in the end of lines when you read the data from `.txt` file. So you should strip the line break in the first.

```
from requests import get

def download(url, filename):
    response = get(url, stream = True)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
    print('Downloaded! ', filename)

with open('NVD_JSON_SOURCE_URLS.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()    
        filename = line.split('/')[-1]
        url = line
        download(url, filename)
```